# iptables command to bridge openstack virtual network

Tags: openstack, iptables, nat

I successfully installed openstack on spare server using the ubuntu single-node installer script. The openstack status page on the underlying ubuntu instance is green across the board. From the host ubuntu instance I can ping / ssh to all of the various openstack instances which have been started on the virtual network.

I now want to access the horizon dashboard from my pc on the local network. (I can't access it from the host ubuntu machine since it is a server install & thus has no desktop to run a web browser on) My local network is 192.168.1.xxx, with the ubuntu server having a static ip of 192.168.1.200. Horizon was installed on an instance with ip 10.0.4.77.

Based on the following blog post, (http://serenity-networks.com/installing-ubuntu-openstack-on-a-single-machine-instead-of-7/) it looks like I need to make an iptables change to the host ubuntu instance to bridge between the two networks. The suggested command from the blog post above is:

$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.250 --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.6.241:443

Which if I modify for my network / install would be:

$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.200 --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.4.77:443

However, I am suspicious this is not the preferred way to do this. First, because the --dport 8000 seems wrong, and second because I was under the impression that neutron should be used to create the necessary bridge.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

> $ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.200 --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.4.77:443

This command has nothing to do with neutron. It just made your ubuntu server a router connecting your local network and openstack private network, so that you can access horizon through ip of local network.

--dport 8000 is not fixed, you can change to any unoccupied port. It only influence the horizon address you enter in address bar.